# Getting edge properties (including related vertices) from boost::adjacency_list

Tags: c++, boost, graph, boost-graph

So, I must have gone through the Boost documentation for an hour today. I must be blind. I have, I hope, a simple question:

How do you get the corresponding vertices for an edge with boost::adjacency_list?

I have the following code which I'm trying to figure out:

```
typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS> Graph;
typedef boost::graph_traits<Graph>::edge_iterator EdgeIterator;
typedef std::pair<EdgeIterator, EdgeIterator> EdgePair;

EdgePair ep;
for (ep = edges(g); ep.first != ep.second; ++ep.first)
{
    // Get the two vertices that are joined by this edge...
}
```

Anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can find the functions you need in [this page](http://www.boost.org/libs/graph/doc/adjacency_list.html) (in the section called "Non-Member Functions"). The ones you need are `source` and `target`.

```
typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS> Graph;
typedef boost::graph_traits<Graph>::edge_iterator EdgeIterator;
typedef std::pair<EdgeIterator, EdgeIterator> EdgePair;
typedef boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor VertexDescriptor;

EdgePair ep;
VertexDescriptor u,v;
for (ep = edges(g); ep.first != ep.second; ++ep.first)
{
    // Get the two vertices that are joined by this edge...
    u=source(*ep.first,g);
    v=target(*ep.first,g);
}
```